# Updating Entity Works Via Running App, Fails in Tests

Tags: json, spring, jpa, testing, spring-boot

Spring 1.3.5

I've done all I can to verify this; the JSON being passed in via Postman is the same JSON I'm generating from my test. Updating the entity via Postman works fine. Updating via `mockMvc` is failing. First, it was failing with a 400 and I was getting the following error:

```
Could not read document: Already had POJO for id (java.lang.Long) [[ObjectId: key=1, type=com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.PropertyBasedObjectIdGenerator, scope=java.lang.Object]] (through reference chain: com.foo.Department["id"])
```

After doing some research, I ended up adding `scope=Department.class` to Department's `@JsonIdentityInfo`. This resolved that issue (although I really don't understand why) and now it fails because it claims the `@OneToOne` relationship property is null, even though when I look at the entity via the debugger is is right there.

Here is my `Department` Entity:

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="id", scope = Department.class)
@JsonRootName(plural = "departments", singular = "department")
public class Department {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  @Size(min = 5, max = 150)
  private String name;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "brand_id")
  @JsonBackReference("brand-departments")
  private Brand brand;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @NotNull
  @JoinColumn(name = "department_group_id")
  private DepartmentGroup departmentGroup;

  @NotNull
  @Size(max = 10)
  private String shortDescription;

  // getters and setters

}
```

Again, everything works just fine via `bootRun` and posting the JSON from Postman. It only breaks when running my test. Here is my test:

```
@Test
public void successfulUpdateDepartment() throws Exception {
  Department existingDepartment = departmentService.first();
  UpdateDepartment department = new UpdateDepartment(existingDepartment.getId(), "Chngd Dep Y", existingDepartment.getShortDescription(), new DepartmentGroupId(departmentGroup.getId()));

  mockMvc.perform(put(URL)
       .contentType(contentType)
       .content(this.json(department)))
       .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have determined why this was working when the app was running but not for tests. the `scope` attribute of `@JsonIdentityInfo` is used in case the ID's overlap. When running the app, Department and DepartmentGroup had different values for `id` but in my tests, they were both 1. Adding `scope` to both entities solved the problem.